# Saving a const pointer (EVP_MD) to a variable in order to re-use it into class method (HMAC)

Tags: c++, pointers, openssl, constants

Let's describe the proper sample issue of a more general problem I'm facing out.
I'm using the `openssl\hmac.h` library in my class. The first argument of `HMAC(...)` function is a const pointer `const EVP_MD*` that defines the hash function to use (`EVP_sha1()`, `EVP_sha256()` etc...)
I would like to save this const pointer to a variable of my class (a property) in order to define/calculate the proper hash function and pass it to a unique call function:

```
HMAC(this->myHashPointer, key, key_len, data, data_len, digest, &digest_len)
```

I can't understant how to define, implement and assign the correct value to the `this->myHashPointer` property.

One of my thoughts was to implement a _pointer to a const EVP_MD pointer`_ as:

```
[...]
EVP_MD * const * myHashPointer;
[...]
```

and to pass the reference of the `const * EVP_MD` returned by `EVP_shaX()`

```
[...]
if (...) {
    evp = & EVP_shaX();
}
[...]
```

but it does not work

Any suggestions to my issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have the `const` in the wrong place, and you don't need an extra level of pointer.  You need `const EVP_MD*` or the equivalent `EVP_MD const*`.  Both of those are "pointer to constant `EVP_MD`".

For example:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(HashType type)
    {
        switch (type) {
        case SHA1:
            myHashPointer = EVP_sha1();
            break;
        case SHA256:
            myHashPointer = EVP_sha256();
            break;
        }
        //...
    }

    std::string hmac(const std::string& data)
    {
        //...
        HMAC(myHashPointer, key, key_len, data.c_str(), data.size(), digest, &digest_len);
        //...
    }
private:
    const EVP_MD* myHashPointer;
    //...
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I was induced by the `const` attribute to see it as a constant term and not as a pointer to a `const` term. Thank you for your suggestion!